# If $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that $P(\cos^2x)=P(\sin^2x)$ which of the following are true

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

If $P(x)$ is a polynomial for all $x$ belongs to $[0,π/2]$ such that $P(\cos^2x)=P(\sin^2x)$ for all $x$ belongs to $[0,π/2]$  which of the following are true:

1. $P(x)$ is an even function
2. $P(x)$ is a polynomial of even degree
3. $P(x)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $(2x-1)^2$

I tried evaluating it as
$$P(\sin^2x) = P(\cos^2x)$$
$$P(\sin^2x) = P(1-\sin^2x)$$
Let $\sin^2x  = y $
The equation becomes $P(y)=P(1-y)$ for all $x$ belongs to $[0,1]$.

Now I don't know how to further find the properties of this polynomial. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: $P(y)=P(1-y)$ for all $y \in [0,1]$ implies $P(y)=P(1-y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1,$$you know that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):P(x)=P(1-x).$$Let $Q(x)=P\left(x+\frac12\right)$. Then\begin{align}Q(-x)&=P\left(-x+\frac12\right)\\&=P\left(1-\left(-x+\frac12\right)\right)\\&=P\left(x+\frac12\right)\\&=Q(x).\end{align}So, $Q(x)$ is even, and therefore $Q(x)=R(x^2)$ for some polynomial $R(x)$. But then$$P(x)=Q\left(x-\frac12\right)=R\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\right),$$and this is equivalent to the third item from your list.

Comment: #2 is also true.

Comment: @lhf Indeed it is.

Answer (score 1):

$P(y)=P(1-y)$ for all $y \in [0,1]$ implies $P(y)=P(1-y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$.

1. False: $P(x)=x(1-x)$ satisfies the condition but is not an even function
2. True: If the degree of $P$ is $n$ and its leading coefficient is $a$, then the leading coefficient of $P(1-y)$ is $(-1)^n a$.
3. Has been answered nicely by José.